# Angular, firebase hosting TypeError: fd(...).auth is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

Cordial saludo colegas, he terminado de desarrollar un pequeño proyecto en angular con firebase, y todo funciona bien en local, mi problema radica al momento de subirlo en firebase hosting, me guie usando este post.
https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/deploy-angular-firebase

Tanto el build como el firebase deploy salen exitosos, pero cuando abro el proyecto en la ruta que da el firebase hosting sale en blanco y en la ventana inspeccionar el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el archivo firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/usbook-admin",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

El package.json

```
{
  "name": "usbook-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "firebase": "^7.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
    "ngx-tags-input": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.10.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.0-0 || ^0.900.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.12.1",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {AngularFireAuthGuard} from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {AngularFireStorage} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import {BsModalRef, ModalModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/progressbar';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgxTagsInputModule } from 'ngx-tags-input';
import { Page404Component } from './page404/page404.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
import { BookModalComponent } from './book-modal/book-modal.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Page404Component,
    NavbarComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BooksComponent,
    BookModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NgxTagsInputModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFireAuth,
    AngularFireAuthGuard,
    AngularFireStorage,
    BsModalRef
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser este error?, ya he revisado las importaciones del auth, y las veo bien, estoy usando angularfire 5.2.1 y angular 9.

Comment: Te recomiendo llevarte de la guía de [Angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire). Veo que usas Firestore y no lo tienes indicado en las importaciones de tu módulo. En lugar de tener AngularFirestore en providers, debes poner `AngularFirestoreModule` en `imports`, y así sucesivamente con cada servicio de Firebase. Recuerda que todo es un módulo y debes indicarlo en `imports` antes de poder usarlo.

Comment: Acabo de hacer lo que dijiste y ya me funciona en el hosting, gracias, pero me causa curiosidad porque en local funciona todo normal sin haber hecho los imports de esos modulos y en el hosting no?

Comment: La respuesta super corta a tu pregunta es, cuando envías tu aplicación a producción (ng build --prod) el agarra todo lo que le hayas indicado en tu módulo para que todos tus componentes y servicios que lo utilicen puedan consumirlos. Como no lo tenías indicado, Angular no lo incluye en la versión de producción y por eso no te funcionaba ya que el no sabía a qué te referías con esa parte del código. Localmente funciona porque Angular busca las librerías en todo tu proyecto incluyendo la carpeta node_modules. Repito, a producción solo va lo que le indiques en tus módulos.